# Python's ElementTree, how to create links in a paragraph

Tags: python, html, elementtree

I have a website I'm building running off Python 2.7 and using ElementTree to build the HTML on the fly. I have no problem creating the elements and appending them to the tree. It's where I have to insert links in the middle of a large paragraph that I am stumped. This is easy when it's done in text, but this is doing it via XML. Here's what I mean:

Sample text:

```
lawLine = "..., a vessel as defined in Section 21 of the Harbors and Navigation Code which is inhabited and designed for habitation, an inhabited floating home as defined in subdivision (d) of Section 18075.55 of the Health and Safety Code, ..."
```

To add that text to the HTML as H4-style text, I typically use:

```
      h4 = ET.Element('h4')
      htmlTree.append(h4)
      h4.text = lawLine
```

I need to add links at the word "Section" and the numbers associated with it, but I can't simply create a new element "a" in the middle of a paragraph and add it to the HTML tree, so I'm trying to build that piece as text, then do ET.fromstring and append it to the tree:

```
      thisLawType = 'PC'
      matches = re.findall(r'Section [0-9.]*', lawLine)
      if matches:
          lawLine = """<h4>{0}</h4>""".format(lawLine)
          for thisMatch in matches:
              thisMatchLinked = """<a href="./index.py?lawtype={0}&lawnumber={1}">{2}</a>""".format(thisLawType, thisMatch.replace('Section ',''), thisMatch)
              lawLine = lawLine.replace(thisMatch, thisMatchLinked)
          htmlBody.append(ET.fromstring(lawLine))
```

I am getting "xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed" errors when I do ET.fromstring. Is there a better way to do this in ElementTree? I'm sure there are better extensions out there, but my work environment is limited to Python 2.7 and the standard library. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
Evan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xml you are generating is indeed not well formed, because of the presence of `&` in `thisMatchLinked`. It's one of the special charcters which need to be escaped ([see an interesting explanation here](https://www.tjohearn.com/2018/01/24/safe-ampersand-parsing-in-xml-files/)).

So try replacing `&` with `&amp;` and see if it works.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!